How to reduce code duplication in the fields of a dataclass?
Each line has a repetition of : str = field(default=""), is there any way to reduce the repetition of code?
@dataclass
class P4File:
    depotFile: str = field(default="")
    clientFile: str = field(default="")
    rev: str = field(default="")
    change: str = field(default="")
    action: str = field(default="")
    fileSize: str = field(default="")
    totalFileSize: str = field(default="")
    totalFileCount: str = field(default="")
    type: str = field(default="")
    time: str = field(default="")

    head_rev: str = field(default="")
    blob: bytes = field(default=b"")
    encoding: str = field(default="")


You can just set them to "", no need for feild

Why would you want to? It is fine as it is. (You don't need to play code-golf.)

If default="" is the only argument you are passing to field, you don't need to call field at all; simply setting the attribute to "" is sufficient.
@dataclass
class P4File:
    depotFile: str = ""
    # etc

Otherwise, field is an ordinary function; you can define a wrapper that calls field with default="" each time, and passes any additional arguments directly to field. dataclass doesn't care if the call to field happens directly in the class statement; it only looks to see if an attribute is defined with a Field value or not.
def myfield(*args, **kwargs):
    # Overriding a given default if necessary
    kwargs['default'] = ""
    return field(*args, **kwargs)


@dataclass
class P4File:
    depotFile: str = myfield()
    clientFile: str = myfield()
    rev: str = myfield()
    change: str = myfield()
    action: str = myfield()
    fileSize: str = myfield()
    totalFileSize: str = myfield()
    totalFileCount: str = myfield()
    type: str = myfield()
    time: str = myfield()

    head_rev: str = myfield()
    blob: bytes = myfield()
    encoding: str = myfield()

If you want to be able to override the "default default", you can do that as well:
def myfield(*args, **kwargs):
    # Only assume default="" if no other default has been given
    kwargs.setdefault('default', "")
    return field(*args, **kwargs)

)
